# In NodeJS's OS module, does any one know what platform Yosemite or Windows8 appears as?

Tags: node.js, windows-8, osx-yosemite, flat

I'm trying to detect the operating system's natural look and feel so I style my elements close to the feel of the OS (e.g. Skeuomorph or Flat).

Currently, I am using NodeJS's 'os' module for getting OS information.  On the Mac [Mavericks] I can get the value 'darwin' via `os.platform()`, which according to wiki, is also what Yosemite is called.

My main aim is to detect if the OS uses a flat design (e.g. the new Windows8 or Mac's Yosemite) or the traditional skeuomorph design.

Is there are list of the platform names for the various OS's?
 - OR alternatively -
Is there a easier/better method to detect if the OS uses a flat or skeuomorph design?

Comment: You can use `os.release()` to determine the version. For example, it returns `6.1.xxxx` on Windows 7, which is [NT 6.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions#Device_versions)

Comment: Thanks Ben, I've looked at that, but on my Mac (Mavericks) i get 13.4.5, which is nothing like the OS's actual 10.9 version number.   What is needed is a list of what numbers/strings mean what OS, so I can build in that logic...

Comment: That's the underlying version of Darwin. You can cross-reference them with the OSX version [here.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29)

Answer (score 3):

Quoting answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160251/173677).

There is now an `os` module: [Node OS Module Docs](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html). It has a function for getting the platform [`os.platform`](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform)

The docs don't give return values. So, I've documented some below. Results are for Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, OS X 10.8.5, Windows 7 64-bit and a Joyent SmartMachine, respectively. Tests conducted on Node 0.10.

### Linux

- `os.type()` :  `'Linux'`
- `os.platform()` : `'linux'`
- `os.arch()` : `'x64'`

### OS X (Mac)

- `os.type()` : `'Darwin'`
- `os.platform()` : `'darwin'`
- `os.arch()` : `'x64'`

### Windows

- `os.type()` : `'Windows_NT'`
- `os.platform()` : `'win32'`
- `os.arch()` : `'x64'`

### SmartMachine

- `os.type()` : `'SunOS'`
- `os.platform()` : `'sunos'`
- `os.arch()` : `'ia32'`

Note: on Windows 7 64-bit node may incorrectly report `os.arch()` as `ia32`. This is a documented bug: [os.arch should be the architecture of the OS not of the process](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2862)

Comment: Any way to differentiate Windows 7 / Windows 8, or Mac Mavericks / Yosemite?   I'm just trying to keep the OS's design consistent.  :)

Comment: @GuyPark Try to play with `os.release()` method.