# How to determine a user's operating system through node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

Is there a way to determine the operating system of the user browsing and also whether it is 64 bit or a 32 bit

Comment: Which "user's" operating system? If it means "web[browser] user" then NodeJS is irrelevant to answering the question; as only data from the browser can be used (such as the easily lied about User Agent header). And if it's not for a "web[browser] user", then the [web] tag is irrelevant.

Comment: use `os.arch()` may be it will give you the system info

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551006/get-my-os-from-the-node-js-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  nodejs built in module `os` for getting  architecture information

[OS module Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html)

```
  var os = require("os");
  console.log(os.arch());  //ia32
```

you can use process object

```
porcess.arch  //'ia32'
```